# Get price from variants object with shopify_api - and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify-app

I'm using shopify_api (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) to create an app for Shopify using Ruby.

For a `Base::Product`, by calling directly `product.variants`, i will have:

```
[#<ShopifyAPI: :Variant: 0x00007fa15cb0e960 @attributes={
"id"=>12664776392816,
"title"=>"Default Title",
"price"=>"5.00",
"sku"=>"",
"position"=>1,
"inventory_policy"=>"deny",
"compare_at_price"=>nil,
"fulfillment_service"=>"manual",
"inventory_management"=>nil,
"option1"=>"Default Title",
"option2"=>nil,
"option3"=>nil,
"created_at"=>"2018-08-27T03:17:24-04:00",
"updated_at"=>"2019-04-07T23:52:00-04:00",
"taxable"=>true,
"barcode"=>"",
"grams"=>0,
"image_id"=>nil,
"weight"=>0.0,
"weight_unit"=>"kg",
"inventory_item_id"=>12758757474416,
"inventory_quantity"=>0,
"old_inventory_quantity"=>0,
"requires_shipping"=>true,
"admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/ProductVariant/12664776392816"
}, @prefix_options={
:product_id=>1389200408688
}, @persisted=true>
]
```

In this case, how do I directly get `price` attribute from this json returned

**EDIT**:
I just jump in ruby on rails in the middle, so here is what I have tried so far:

`product.variants.prices` --> in my guts it definitely does not work, but might as well trying
returns with `undefined method`price' for #`

parse the JSON

1) `JSON.parse(product.varient)['price']`
returns with
`no implicit conversion of Array into String`

2) `variant = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(product.variants[0])` 
or `variant = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(product.variants)`

then

`variant['price']`

but both return with `no implicit conversion of ShopifyAPI::Variant into String`

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hey @Kris, i edited the post for what I tried

Comment: **product.variants.map(&:price)** because product has many variants array.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AshokDamaniya, please create an answer so I can mark this. Anyway, do you have any recommend document relates to this for ruby? (like when should we use `:`, `&`, or `=>`...) i'm just a beginner jumping in the middle of no where

Comment: sorry @Jacky i don't have any specific doc for this right now , but will try to find and attach here for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(shopify_product_id)
product.variants.map(&:price)
```

it will give you an array of price because product might have multiple variants.
you can also use **.pluck** method instead of **.map**